# Get the number of records processed by a saved import (MS Access, VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working with Microsoft Access.  I am executing a saved import (from an Excel spreadsheet) via VBA using the `DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport` command.  I would like to ***programmatically*** capture the number of records processed by this saved import.

The MS documentation on `DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport` does not indicate there are any return values or ByRef parameters that I can use.

I searched Google and SO, expecting an answer, as I would think this has already been addressed.  If I missed an answer out there on the interweb, please let me know!

Here is the code I am using.  I'm happy to use a different method of importing my spreadsheet if it can give me the number of rows.

```
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "<name of saved import>"
```

I'd like something like:

```
numRec = DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport("<name of saved import>")
debug.print "# rec loaded="& numRec
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible with RunSavedImportExport but an alternative would be to check the table your importing to. If it's an append import you can count the number of records before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed not available using `DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport`

Instead, you can use a query to do the import, and `Database.RecordsAffected`

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "SELECT * INTO SomeTable FROM [Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=C:\Path\To\File.xlsx].[MyNamedRange]"
debug.print "# rec loaded="& db.RecordsAffected
```

You can adjust the query to be an append query if you need to append records to a table.

Comment: Very helpful and much appreciated.  I marked your response as Answered.